# Why is "arrive" an answer for the crossword clue "like desert terrain"?

Tags: crossword-clues

Possible source: https://nytminicrossword.com/nyt-mini-crossword-answers-january-14-2020/

[image]

ACROSS
1. Listen to
5. Desolate
7. Like desert terrain
8. Lines of work
9. Monopoly purchases
10. Armed conflicts

DOWN
1. Tilling tool
2. List of mistakes
3. More like the desert
4. Delights
5. Spa attraction
6. Loch ____ monster

I've tried finding any possible link between "desert" and "arrive" and had no success. I need to know.

Comment: how sure are you that it is indeed the correct answer for that clue?  Does the crossword have any gimmicks that you know of?

Comment: Is it possible you can add an image from the crossword so we can see how 'arrive' was found to be the word for that clue? I know off the top of my head with those letters and that clue I'd think something more along the lines of arid (obviously not long enough but a word related to it) would make sense. Also if you do this ensure to include reference to the source.

Comment: ...is this a quick clue or a cryptic one? (I'd guess the former.) Did you see the solution or is "arrive" something you feel fits with other answers you've filled in of which you feel sure? As a quick clue for 6 letters I'd think it was "barren".

Comment: Given the edit, I wonder if the clue was just a printing mistake.  Perhaps "7. Like desert terrain" was a previous version of the clue "5. Desolate" (answer Barren in both cases) and was printed by mistake instead of the actual clue that was meant for 7-across?

Comment: @JS1 I think so too -- seems appropriate, given 2-Down!

Comment: @JS1: I reckon #5 is the older one. It seems likely to me that they wanted to rephrase clue #5 to be more similar to #3down, but accidentally replaced #7 instead.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I suggest writing that as an answer, because I'd say that is very likely what has happened.

Comment: I just found this website, which suggest that "arrive" is in fact a common answer for this exact clue: https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/like-desert-terrain.  Now I am equally puzzled.

Comment: @earlien I wouldn't say it is common. That entry was added on January 13. Also, that website lists the answers for the clues even if they were suggested by a single user

Comment: @melfnt Perhaps I misinterpreted it. I should say the answer of “arrive” for that clue had a rank of 4 out of 5 stars. But I’m not sure how it is ranked. At this stage, I still think the clue was likely in error.

Comment: I'm with @JS1 here - the clue should probably have been 'to reach a destination'. (the idea being that 'desert' and 'destination' have several letters in common...)

Comment: I've found a couple of sources like @earlien did.  My guess is that the setters are using the same tools as we are, and came across this clue.  So the printing error may have happened in a previous puzzle, and internet crossword tools have made it canon.

Answer (score 2):

The printing mistake (substitution of a second clue for 5 across, as in JS1's comment) is the most likely option.

But - stretching credulity to the limit - if you assume the puzzle maker wanted to add a single cryptic clue to their puzzle then there is an alternate solution.

- Desert terrain is dry, so would typically be *without a river*.
- The prefix a- (from the Greek) can be used to mean *not* or *without*, for example in *atonal* = without tone.
- So adding a- to the root word river, *a-river* or *ariver* could, at a stretch mean without river.
- And (ta-dahhh!) ARIVER is an anagram for ARRIVE.

I rest my (very weak) case m'laud, and ask for the court's mercy.

Comment: This seems very unlikely - that's not how cryptic clues work, and that would immediately be thrown out by any remotely competent editor.